# Auto change spelling from US to UK english using php

Tags: php

The texts for each of my pages are defined in external language files. For example in www.example.com/about_us.php I write:

```
require('includes/languages/english/about_us.php');
```

Then I simply echo the desired text to see the result.

```
echo TEXT_ABOUT_US;
```

How can I auto change the spelling in includes/languages/english/about_us.php from US English to UK English?

In www.example.com/about_us.php, I know I can use str_replace for each text I want to show, but that will be very time consuming to implement:

```
$us_words = array('colors','flavors');
$uk_words = array('colours', 'flavours');

echo str_replace($us_words,$uk_words,TEXT_ABOUT_US);
```

Instead of writing str_replace as above for all texts I want to echo, I wish to auto change all texts when they are picked up by:

```
require('includes/languages/english/about_us.php');
```

Is this somehow possible?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is.  If you have an existing standard for external language files, can't you just have one for US English and one for UK English?  I doubt there's any automatic translation feature, though there may be some libraries out there which can help.  I wouldn't expect 100% accuracy though, language is a very tricky thing to concretely and logically define.

Comment: Word-for-word translation without context will give you some strange errors - try googling for "HMS Bonnet"

Comment: with regex, it may give undesired result.

Comment: I could copy all my US English files and translate them manually to UK English, but I would prefer to auto change basic words such as "color" to "colour" when they are picked up from my US spelling version.

How can the be done? Is regex the solution? How?

Comment: SMART: "I could copy all my US English files and translate them manually to UK English".  "But I would prefer to auto change basic words such as "color" to "colour": PROBABLY NOT SUCH A GOOD IDEA...

Answer (score 2):

You certainly would *not* want to repeatedly translate a file on-the-fly. That's a waste of CPU cycles. Also, as others pointed out, machine translations can do odd things, even within a "single" language like English. Do it once (semi-manually), have some directory mechanism for selecting the version of English (en_US, en_UK, en_ZA, etc.) and just read the files over and over.

Any decent editor can bulk change 'color' to 'colour' or vice-versa. Just be sure to manually confirm that all changes were justified and appropriate. "find" and "replace" are usually one keystroke to find the next one, and one keystroke to do the replacement if you decide it's correct.

By any chance is this for osCommerce? The directory structure and macro names look a lot like osC. Unfortunately, I don't recall its having any mechanism to choose from among multiple possible Englishes.